# Google Cloud endpoints module to Google Cloud module with GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an app with a regular Google Cloud Endpoints module. Everything works fine. But recently, I found out that I need to have GCM service for the app. Is it possible to convert the Google Cloud Endpoints module to a Google Cloud messaging module? Or should I have both modules and deploy in different cloud projects? Or should I just set up the whole backend again with a GCM module? I am using Android Studio with Gradle btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your new API to your existing module; you don't have to do anything special.